# Rails 3 Model.all alternative?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I have a number of Model.all queries in collections in my view (using them for drop down lists to populate a form). Some of the lists returned have many records and it's taking a long time to load the edit view as a result.

Is there an alternative to calling .all in the following?

```
= f.input :descriptivedetail_primarycontenttype, :label => "Content type", :as => :select, :collection => Contenttype.all, :value_method => :code
```

I can't use a scope as I get the error

`undefined method 'first' for :allisbns:Symbol`

where :allisbns is

`scope :allisbns, Isbn.all`

in the model.

Thanks!

Comment: This made it a bit faster: 

View: 

    `:collection =>  @allistcs`

Controller: 

      `def edit
         @isbn = Isbn.find(params[:id])
         @allisbns = Isbn.all_isbns
      end`

Model: 

      `def self.all_isbns  
        all 
      end`

Comment: How large is your ISBN table, and how many fields are there? You might be able to speed up the query by limiting which fields are selected.

Comment: Thanks for replying: I hacked away a load of fields this morning, so it's now got 46 columns. At the moment there are only 286 records, but this is going to rise to around 250,000, which is why I'm worried. Limiting the fields sounds very sensible, now you mention it - do you just do Isbn.all.fieldname ?

Comment: Consider using fragment caching and/or AJAX auto-completion ?

Comment: Fragment caching I'm doing, but it's not making much difference - but Ajax autocompletion - that's interesting - thank you.

Comment: @snowangel - You could do `Isbn.select(:fieldname).map(&:fieldname)`, but if you've got thousands of records, it's going to take a performance hit in the browser too.